# Android SurfaceView cover with a view，but view‘s color will become dark

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have a `SurfaceView` that is covered with a view, this view is semitransparent，but this `SurfaceView` lets the view's color become dark.

If we show a Toast with Activity, the view's color will become light. When the Toast is dismissed, the view's color also become dark. How to resolve this problem?

there is my layoutXml file :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/full_screen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    >

    <cn.home.widget.MoveSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/move_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <cn.home.widget.SlidingMenuView
        android:id="@+id/home_sliding_menu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/help_img"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>
```

MoveSurfaceView is this SurfaceView ,this SlidingMenuView is a HorizontalScrollView
this MoveSurfaceView is do this:

```
    while (flag) {
        mCanvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        if (mCanvas != null) {
            draw();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

  void draw(){
      mCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
      mCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap_bg, mBitposX, 0, mPaint);
  }
```

Comment: what did u tried? show us some code related to the question.

Comment: I am already add some code

Comment: This happens also to me, were you able to solve it?